# Laravel with Sweet Alert redirect

Tags: php, laravel, sweetalert

I have made a delete modal with Sweet Alert in Laravel and it is deleting user I choose. I would however after deletion like to redirect back to users list as my `destroy()` method says.

```
<script>
    $('a#delete_user').on('click', function () {
        var url = $(this).attr("data-href");
        swal({
                title: "Delete user?",
                text: "Submit to delete",
                type: "warning",
                showCancelButton: true,
                closeOnConfirm: false,
                confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                confirmButtonText: "Delete!"
            },
            function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: url,
                        data: {
                            _method: 'DELETE',
                            _token: csrf_token
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data)
                                swal("Deleted!", "User has been deleted", "success");
                            else
                                swal("cancelled", "User has not been deleted", "error");
                        }
                    }), 2000
                });
            });
    })
</script>
```

Here is the controller:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    User::destroy($id);
    return redirect('users')->with('status', 'User Deleted!');
}
```

I would like to redirect to users list with message, and I have trouble doing so

Answer (score 1):

In your main template file or in view file, you have to check **if there is status data in session**, if yes so you call sweet alert. Example code:

```
@if (session('status'))
    <script>
        $( document ).ready(
            swal("{{ session('status') }}")
        });
    </script>
@endif
```

Comment: I have it already, it doesn't get triggered. And if I set `location.reload()` then no status is forwarded

Comment: You have to check what is not triggering - the sweet alert call, or maybe session('status') is empty so if statement is not executing code inside?

Comment: My solution will work only if you will delete ajax request in delete user button. When you use ajax call, the redirect part in controller won't work.

Comment: But if I delete ajax request, how will I trigger the route?

Comment: If you want to call destroy method from controller you have to create a form. e.g.: <form action="{{ action('UserController@destroy', $user->id) }}" method="delete"> + <button type="submit">delete user</button>

Comment: I know, but with this option, I can't use Sweet Alert, right?

Comment: Of course you can! Look, actually you are calling sweetalert with ajax request, after you click that button. My solution is, to just leave normal button without any ajax requests and any js at all. Your controller will redirect you to page with users list WITH message hidden in session. That code what I have given will check if there is any message, if there is, sweet alert will appear with message from session. I hope you understand what I mean :)

Answer (score 0):

Edit js file like this:

```
success: function (data) {
if (data == 'success')
    swal("Deleted!", "User has been deleted", "success");
    window.location('Your URL');
else
    swal("cancelled", "User has not been deleted", "error");
}
```

and the controller:

```
if(User::destroy($id)){
    return 'success';
}else{
    return 'fail';
}
```